# Do wireless charging adapters interfere with NFC?

Tags: nfc, wireless-charging

I've just got a Huawei P30 (standard, not Pro or Lite) and realised it doesn't feature NFC - with no less than 4 wireless chargers in my house and 2 in my office. But I use Google Pay all the time - in many ways I rely on it.

I've done some Googling and I can't find much info about this - the closest I came was an article about wireless charging slowly damaging the NFC controller chip over time in a Nexus 7 due to a circuitry flaw.

Would adding a Qi adapter pad inside a case affect the data-only NFC on the device? With it not being a native feature, I can imagine there may be some safety drawbacks to the internal antenna and circuitry.

But at the same time, Huawei had an official wireless charging case available. So, maybe it's not a problem for the P30?

Answer (score 1):

TLDR;
Qi wireless charging can damage NFC tags and readers.

I don't have any experience with using Qi adapters and NFC in conjunction but I would imagine there would be some interference.

Depending on the position of your NFC chip, the Qi adapter may partially or completely cover the chip. Whilst this would only be a very thin layer of metal obstructing the chip, the interference would largely depend on the quality of the NFC chip.

I do have a wireless charging mount in my car that I have previously placed an NFC tag on. I was able to charge my phone (Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge and Note 9) perfectly, however, my phone struggled to consistently read the NFC tag. It would often either not read the tag at all or would repeatedly read it, which was very frustrating as the routine I had set up would send multiple messages to my wife.

So, it would seem that wireless charging and NFC can interfere with each other if not implemented correctly. If this is a risk you can not afford to take, then I would suggest sticking with a charger cable or perhaps a [magnetic charger cable](https://www.google.com/search?q=magnetic%20charging%20cable) for more convenience.

---

Following OP's comment I have done some more research regarding NFC degradation caused by Qi wireless charging and have come across [this](https://www.rfidjournal.com/articles/view?18282) article from RFID Journal.

The article details an NFC-enabled wireless charging system for cars and, although it doesn't specify any sort of statistics, it does state that NFC tags can be damaged by wireless charging.

> NFC devices are also commonly stored in the wallets, purses and pockets of individuals for payments, access control and more. NFC tags, however, can be damaged or destroyed by the magnetic fields of wireless chargers, creating a potential conflict for a variety of NFC technology products

I wasn't completely satisfied with this.

I changed my search criteria to specifically look for details on NFC readers and it wasn't long before I cam across a post on the Nordic Semiconductor DevZone forum regarding [Qi wireless charging damaging an NFC reader](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/f/nordic-q-a/50101/nfc-pins-broken-because-of-qi-charger-how-to-do-qi-nfc).
In the thread one of Nordic Semiconductor's support staff responds with the following

> Yes, QI currents can damage NFC readers/tags, and what you're describing does not seem reversible. Sorry about that. Although we can't guarantee anything, adding the extra capacitor seems to protect the NFC tag sufficiently, so I suggest you give it a go. Additionally, it wouldn't hurt disabling the NFC while you're charging either, but I don't believe it to be crucial.

So, given this information and OP stating that NFC doesn't work with wireless chargers (at least that's my understanding of OP), I would be inclined to believe Huawei disables the NFC reader while charging wirelessly in order to protect the NFC reader from damage.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'm not so worried about interference as such, I'm worried about whether the native data-only NFC can handle the field that the Qi adapter accepts, or whether the charging will cause damage to the native circuitry.

Comment: @BrandonPowell I have extended my answer to include some extra Googling. I fear I might still have not answered your question properly though. Please could you clarify a couple of points for me. Are you saying that NFC doesn't work **whilst** you are charging your phone wirelessly or that NFC no longer functions **after** using wireless chargers? Also, are you using the official Huawei wireless charging case or a 3rd party adapter?